# Windows 10 possible Performance Degradation after Update

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-update, updates, automatic-update

I have a laptop that runs Win10 build 1507. Today when I booted it up, Windows flashed the Update Assisstant and said I needed to Update. The machine in question is from 2014, with a core i5-4210U and 4GB of RAM, but most importantly, a 5400 RPM HDD, which suffers already due to high amounts of disk access. Will an update further reduce performance on this system, is there an increase in performance requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since you can run Windows 10 1507 fine, don’t need to worry about the requirements of 1709 version, same as 1507.

About your concern, it’s reasonable:

Because 5400rpm is the proper choice when you use HDD to store large files, for example, store backups, movies, pictures and etc.

However, when the HDD needs to act as a system drive, running applications from it that care about latency instead of throughput, you’d better pick 7200rpm HDDs or even better SSDs.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't add an SSD or a high speed drive because there's no additional slot, not even an M.2. Looks like I'll have to grit my teeth and deal with it.